Error to import ipcRenderer(electron) on React component
I'm developing a simple application with Electron where I want to implement a custom TitleBar. The issue arises when I try to use ipcRenderer to handle window close and minimize functionalities. I encounter the following error just by attempting to import ipcRenderer:
Failed to compile
./node_modules/electron/index.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
I've read about changing the Next.js configuration file, something like this, but it still throws an error. In the newer versions, the file is named next.config.mjs:
`@type {import('next').NextConfig} \*/
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
output: 'export',
images: {
unoptimized: true,
},
// webpack(config, { isServer }) {
//   if (!isServer) {
//     config.target = 'electron-renderer';
//   }
//   return config;
// }
}

export default nextConfig`

React component - TitleBar
`import React from 'react'
import { Icons } from '@/components/Icons'
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

export default function TitleBar() {
const handleOnCloseWindow = () =\> {
window.close()
}

const handleOnMinimize = () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('minimize-window')
}
}`

Technologies:
Electron: 29.3.1
Next.js: 14.1.3
React: 18.2.0
